# How to rebase certain branch to master branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I cloned certain branch from github project/repository like this:

```
git clone repo -b name
```

I now need to rebase it to master branch.

```
git rebase master
```

But I cannot do that.

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream master
```

What should I do to make it possible? I am new to github.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your upstream was fetched or not? To do that, simply

`git fetch upstream`

And now rebase by

`git rebase origin/master`

Hope that helped.

Comment: After <git fetch upstream> I got this> fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository> . Should I somehow clone the master branch also?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork
Follow the instructions on this. This will create a new remote repository that points to yours. After you're done, execute `git fetch upstream`.